# How to distinct "pause" and "shutdown" event with PhoneGap

Tags: events, cordova, shutdown

I'm developing a PhoneGap app who is retrieving values from a distant server.

When my app is going to be paused, it goes to the background and stop getting datas, but keep errors tracked when listening. All is okay.

My question is how to detect "shut down" event with PhoneGap, because I want to do other stuffs when my app is shutting down than when it's pausing.

In other words, I can do `document.addEventListener('pause', this.onDevicePause, false);` and I wonder to know if a sort of `document.addEventListener('unload', this.onDeviceUnload, false);` exists.

Thanks for your help.
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Provided by this link, I think that even if I can get a sort of "ondestroy" event, it would probably not work because the app is killed.

[Handle onDestroy method in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610270/handle-ondestroy-method-in-javascript)

I think I will play with the "pause" event and some imaginary stuffs ;-)